# App Crashes whenever I click an Icon on Navigation bar

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, navigationbar

Just got many problems sorted out on my bottom navigation bar, but now the app crashes whenever I click on any of the 3 navigation bar Icons.

**Error**

```
 2020-07-23 15:41:26.397 25876-25876/com.example.sociate11 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sociate11, PID: 25876
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction.doAddOp(FragmentTransaction.java:245)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.doAddOp(BackStackRecord.java:180)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction.replace(FragmentTransaction.java:343)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction.replace(FragmentTransaction.java:293)
        at com.example.sociate11.activityHome$2.onNavigationItemSelected(activityHome.java:67)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(BottomNavigationView.java:243)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView$1.onClick(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:124)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7357)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7334)
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:808)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28200)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7478)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
```

**activityHome.java**

```
    package com.example.sociate11;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class activityHome extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private Button logout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        logout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogOut);

        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                firebaseAuth.signOut();
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(activityHome.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });

        BottomNavigationView bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_bar);
        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navListener);

       if (savedInstanceState == null) {
           getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                   new HomeFragment()).commit();
       }
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navListener =
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    Fragment selectedFragment = null;

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.home_fragment:
                            selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.events_fragment:
                            selectedFragment = new EventFragment();
                            break;
                        case R.id.fragment_myconversation:
                            selectedFragment = new ConversationFragment();
                            break;
                    }

                    assert selectedFragment != null;
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                            selectedFragment).commit();

                    return true;
                }
            };
    }
```

**ConversationsFragment.java** (all 3 fragments are currently identical)

```
    package com.example.sociate11;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class ConversationFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_myconversations,container,false);
    }
}
```

**bottom_navigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_home"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_myEvents"
        android:title="My Events"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_event"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_myConversations"
        android:title="My Conversations"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_conversations"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

**activity_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activityHome"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogOut"
        android:layout_width="115dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:text="log out"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation_bar" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnLogOut"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Thank you for the help as always, and please let me know if I didn't provide enough info!

Comment: Are you sure that those `R.id`s in the `case` statements match those in the menu XML for your `BottomNavigationView`?

Comment: yes, they match

Comment: Please post the layout that contains your `<BottomNavigationView>`, and the menu XML for that `BottomNavigationView`. Please also specify the exact names of both files when you post them.

Comment: those two now edited in

Comment: You have the wrong IDs in the `case` statements. Those need to be the IDs from the menu XML; e.g., `case R.id.menu_home:`.

Comment: Ahhhh I was looking at the wrong id's! thank you! I spent so long staring at it I can't believed I missed it!